# Rendering Grass Using Repeating Images In CSS

Tags: html, css

I want to create a large field of grass, using only a series of small blocks or slices that will repeat in a clever way.  I think [the cicada principle](http://designfestival.com/the-cicada-principle-and-why-it-matters-to-web-designers/) could be used to achieve this, but I'm not sure how to apply it for a grass effect.

As a concrete example, consider this image:

[image: Grass]

Can anyone recreate this using slices or squares of small dimensions (eg, slices only a few pixel wide, or only a few pixel tall if they were horizontal, or squares 5x5 or smaller)?  The final product need not be an exact match of the original, just something that looks similar.  The solution should be able to create a field of grass able to fill up a div of any needed dimensions.  Any repetition in the field should be seamless and hard to detect at a glance (as it is in the curtain example from the link above).

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Have you attempted to solve this problem yourself? We help with problems, not do them for you.

Comment: The easiest option would probably be to Photoshop an image to tile seamlessly. I'm not sure why you'd want to create this with CSS.

Comment: I have thought about it, and don't know how to get started.  Yes, creating slices in photoshop will obviously be part of the solution.  The question is: what should the slices (or squares) look like, and how should they be repeated?

Comment: Here is a [grass sample](http://designfestival.com/cicada/break-it-down/?id=26) on the cicada project page. That should get you started.

Comment: Thanks topek.  If you want to go ahead and add that as your answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: This may be off-topic, but what is the point in this and not use a ready-to-go image? I don't see any advantage in this method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start of by creating a seamless pattern image to use as a background. See [this](http://psd.tutsplus.com/articles/how-a-turn-a-texture-into-a-seamlessly-tiled-background/) tutorial for instance.

When you have your seamless pattern image, just use it as a background in a div, and repeat it using the background-repeat css-property.

```
.your-div
{
background-image:url('seamless-pattern-image.png');
background-repeat:repeat;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you open your image in PhotoShop, just crop the image at 3 sizes, and apply below structure as a mask.

[image: layer mask]

For better result, blur the mask, so that it does not have hard edges.